# What is the difference between google's dataflow and talend ?

Tags: bigdata, talend, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am trying to see through the technical performance of both technologies and put up a benchmark for that reason.
Could you guys help me with that ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It will be tricky to do that, google is serverless tech, and charges on a job/per minute basis and therefore in essence runs on there own servers. Where talend although can run aws and support a type of serverless tech this is not out of the box and would take sometime to come up with sensible comparisons at a deep technical level. For myself, if you don't need to get deep and dirty for performance and have relatively simplistic data transformations then I would tend to favor Google (if you don't mind lock-in and the price!) but otherwise I would go for Talend (good to be a java centric development house, and takes more time to make performant etc) Anyway that would be my take on it.

Comment: +1. One clarification about about 'lock-in'. Apache Beam (this is API you would write Dataflow applications) allows you to run your application on multiple platforms : Dataflow, Flink, Spark, Apex (and more are being added). In this sense Beam is the most portable API for data processing applications (both streaming and batch). Another excellent portability benefit of Beam is that you can write applications in Java, Python, (soon) Go, etc.